# Display only limited no of records in grid using Ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-grid

I am having trouble making a grid using Ext js .so for i did store and grid.it is working fine.but my problem is,i have 14000 record,it is displayed in a grid ,single shot.but i want to display only 100 records and next 100 records like a page display.i used the paging toolbar but still i am not get it.
please some body help me by posting your code.
thanks in advance.
[sorry for my english]

```
function some function(url)
  {
Ext.define('some model', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: some fields
      });
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
        id:'store',
        model:'some model',
        remoteGroup:true,
        remoteSort:true,
        proxy: {
            type:'rest',
            url:url
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            root:"myroot",
            idProperty:'id'
        }
        },
        autoLoad:true
}); 
return store;
}


var store= some function(url);
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                        id:'Grid',
                        title:'__________',
                        store: store,
                        loadMask: true,
                        width:'100%',
                        autoHeight:true,
                        viewConfig: {
                            emptyText:'No Available'
                        },
                        frame:false,
                        columns:[
                        {
                        id: 'c',
                        header:'bla',
                        dataIndex:'12',
                        width:'35%',
                        sortable:true,
                        },
                        {
                        id: 's',
                        header:'bla',
                        dataIndex:'21212',
                        width:'65%',
                        sortable:true,
                        }
                        ],
                     bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                            store:store,
                            pageSize:10,
                            id:'paging',
                            displayInfo:true,
                            displayMsg:'Displaying  {0} - {1} of {2}',
                            emptyMsg: "No Available",
                            prependButtons:false

                        }),
                       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grid should something like this

```
Ext.define('Com.grid.myGrid',{
            extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
            alias:'widget.myGridAlias',
            store:'myStore',
                initComponent:function()
                {
                     this.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                             store : this.store,
                             displayInfo : true,
                             displayMsg : 'Records {0} - {1} of {2}',
                             emptyMsg : 'No files.' 
                     });
                }
});
```

and and your Store should something like this

```
Ext.define('Com.store.myStore',{
        extend:'Ext.data.Store',
        model : 'myModel',
        //autoLoad:true,
        pageSize: 100
});
```

Comment: You have to define pageSize in your store.

Comment: after that try store.loadPage(1);

Comment: Where should i add this line. in side store, or grid.... please make it clear..:(

Comment: inside store.. I already gave you example of defining store. I mentioned pageSize: 100 over there.

Comment: and store.loadPage(1); you can add anywhere once your code is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This type of examples are already mentioned in Ext Js Sencha document.
Here is the [Link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/paging.html)